# Shared logic for Multiple HttpPost method in Web API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have Multiple HttpPost methods in Web API controller and I also need to check for certain conditions for all of them. how can i add this logic in the controller without repeating the code in each method?
example:

```
public class OnboardingController : ApiController
// can i check for conditions before the code enters to any of the httpPost?

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Onboarding/Method1", Name = "Onboarding/Method1")]

// some code

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Onboarding/Method2", Name = "Onboarding/Method2")]

// some code
```

Comment: What kind of do conditions do you want to check? Is each condition specific to each method or do you have a set of conditions that should be applied to all of the methods? What do you want to be done if condition is not met?

Comment: set of conditions that will be applied to all. inside of try and catch perhaps

Comment: for example if user dont have permissions the code will not entrer any of the httpPost routes

Comment: That sort of thing should be handled via the Authorization system.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with filters. They allow you to intercept requests and perform some actions before control is passed to controllers and their methods. E.g., you can log request parameters or return 403 Not Authorized if a user has no access the requested endpoint.

There are few built-in filters and you can also create your own filters.

Read more about filters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0

This article shows how to use built-in Authorize filter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0